# 16u Channel to 8u Channel for OpenCV Blob tracking

Tags: opengl, opencv

Can anyone tell my why this doesnt work?

```
void CVBlobTrack::updateKinect(ImageSourceRef kdepth, ImageSourceRef kcolor) {
cv::Mat input;
cv::Mat output;

channel16 = Channel16u(kdepth);



// Conversion from 16 bit int to 8 bit int for blob track

//uint16_t *largeImage = (uint16_t *)channel16.getData();
//uint8_t *smallImage = (uint8_t *)channel8.getData();

for (int y = 0; y < 480; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < 640; x++)
    {
        uint8_t c = floor(float(channel16.getValue(Vec2i(x,y))) / 65545.0f * 255.0f );                         

        // This needs to change as its slooooooooooow
        channel8.setValue(Vec2i(x,y), c);

    }
}


writeImage("test", channel8, "png");

cvSetData(mKinectDepthImage8, channel8.getData(), mKinectDepthImage8->widthStep);
```

Writing the image out to disk works fine. Trying to use the channel as data OR AS A CINDER GL_TEXTURE does NOT work. Simply put, the values are being written into the channel (i believe) and yet for whatever reason, only 1 contour is found when i blob track and the texture comes out totally black.

I've tried bit shifting and also printing out the values as opposed to converting to float and many other methods and it always results in a black texture on the screen and only 1 contour found.

```
void CVBlobTrack::draw() {
if(channel8) {
    gl::Texture ttex = gl::Texture(channel8);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    ttex.bind();
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    gl::color(Color::white());

    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(0.0f, 0.0f,0.0f);

    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(640.0f, 0.0f,0.0f);

    glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(640.0f, 480.0f ,0.0f);

    glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(0.0f, 480.0f,0.0f);
    glEnd();

    ttex.unbind();
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}
```

}